# BindingResult isn't detecting JSR:303 annotation based errors

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC. I am trying a simple application to validate form values. I am use Spring BindingResult and JSR303 for field validation. But for some reason the validation errors don't show up in the error tag. In fact, the binding result doesn't return any errors.

My bean is as follows:

```
package com.app.ebl.bean.login;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;


public class LoginBean {

  @NotNull(message = "User Name field can not be blank")
  @Size(max = 10, message = "User Name should not be more than 10 characters")
  private String userName;

  private String password;

  public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
  }

  public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }



}
```

My Controller Class Look like below,

```
package com.app.ebl.controller.login;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.app.ebl.bean.login.LoginBean;


@Controller
public class LoginController {
  private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(LoginController.class);

  @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String toLogin(Model model)
  {
    model.addAttribute("login",new LoginBean());
    return "login";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/authenticate", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public String authenticate(@ModelAttribute(value = "login") @Valid LoginBean login,
      BindingResult bindingResult, Model model)
  {

    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
      return "login";
    }

    model.addAttribute("userName",login.getUserName());
    return "home";
  }

}
```

Now If I provide no value in the user name field, system is not validating the same, and allowing me to the next view.

Can someone please help me.
Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Your code looks ok. Have you added `hibernate-validation.jar` to your project (not only `validation-api.jar`)?

Comment: Will it work if you replace `@Size` with `@Length` (or `@NotEmpty`/`@NotBlank`?

Comment: I have added the dependency for validation-api.                                   But whenever I am trying add the below,                                     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
</dependency>                                                                  Eclipse is showing me the error "Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:
 5.1.1.Final"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Size` annotation accepts both min and max parameter. When `min` is not provided, it uses default:

```
/**
 * @return size the element must be higher or equal to
 */
int min() default 0;
```

You didn't provided any, and my guess is that your controller do not transform empty strings to null. Firstly, I'd switch to `@NotBlank` annotation from `org.hibernate.validator`. In addition to `@NotNull`, it removes trailing whtespaces:

```
public class LoginBean {

  @NotBlank(message = "User Name field can not be blank")
  @Size(max = 10, message = "User Name should not be more than 10 characters")
  private String userName;
....
```

Additionally, define init binder in your controller, that will change empty strings to null with help of `StringTrimmerEditor` from `org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor`

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The issue is solved now. Indeed I am getting blank instead of null. Also hibernate-validator jar was required. Thanks for the piece of code that is now trimming the spaces as well.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to figure this out, I hope this helps someone.

I had the same problem. The bean just wasn't getting validated.

What I had done was created a library via the "buildpath" menu and added the hibernate-validator.jar to my library. I could use the hibernate annotations and I wasn't getting any compile errors but when I ran it, the beans never got validated.

The reason was that the application needed the hibernate-validator.jar in WEB-INF/lib folder, so that it could use it for validation.

Comment: I mean, 5 years after this helps me a lot :):):)